# How the Node* type value is returning in Iterator type?

Tags: c++, c++17

I created a linked list class having a head pointer of type Node.
In the method  `begin()`, I want to return an Iterator type object.
But if I return a pointer of type Node* in the  `begin()` method instead, it is able to compile and run properly. Why???

```
class LinkedList {
    class Node;
    Node* head;

public:
    class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;
        Node(int item) : data{ item }, next{ } { }
    };

    void insert(std::initializer_list<int> list) {
        head = nullptr;
        Node* ptr{};
        for (auto ele : list) {
            if (head == nullptr) {
                head = new Node(ele);
                ptr = head;
                continue;
            }
            
            ptr->next = new Node(ele);
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    void printList() {
        Node* ptr = head;
        
        while (ptr) {
            std::cout << ptr->data << " ";
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

class Iterator {
        Node* m_ptr;
    public:
        std::forward_iterator_tag o1;
        std::ptrdiff_t p1{};
        using value_t = Node;
        using pointer_t = Node*;
        using reference_t = Node&;

        Iterator(pointer_t ptr) : m_ptr{ ptr } {}
        
        reference_t operator*() { return *m_ptr; }
        pointer_t operator->() { return m_ptr; }
        Iterator& operator++() {
            m_ptr++;
            return *this;
        }
        Iterator operator++(int) {
            pointer_t temp = m_ptr;
            ++m_ptr;
            return temp;
        }
        friend bool operator==(const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b) { return a.m_ptr == b.m_ptr; }
        friend bool operator!=(const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b) { return a.m_ptr != b.m_ptr; }

    };

    Iterator begin() { return head; }
    Iterator end() {
        Node* ptr = head;
        
        while (ptr->next != nullptr) {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }

        return ptr;
    }
};
```

Comment: Your iterator class has a converting constructor from `Node*`.

Comment: This looks like a linked list. The right way to increment an iterator on a linked list would be `m_ptr = m_ptr->next;` not `m_ptr++;`.

Comment: Dose converting constructor is implicitly provided by the compiler.

Comment: It may be more convenient to define the `end` iterator as any iterator that has a `m_ptr == nullptr;`. You can generate it in constant time, and the iterator to the last element should implicitly increment to point to `nullptr;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It implicitly converts Node* to Iterator via the Iterator(pointer_t ptr) constructor.